# python - Re module leaving space for matched string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, re-python

I am using re module in python to remove occurence of certain string. Below is what I am trying:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = re.sub(re.compile('ab'), "", 'This is a ab text')
>>> t
'This is a  text'
```

Note that in above instead of replacing 'ab' with '' (nothing) its replacing it with a space.
Can someone please suggest whats the issue here ?

Comment: It replaces `ab` but the space before and the one after it remains. Can you explain what's wrong? What's the desired output?

Comment: got it, my bad, did not realize the space before and after.

Answer (score 5):

The replacement in fact is empty string, but because `ab` is surrounded by spaces on both sides, it appears that the replacement has a space.  Try this version:

```
t = re.sub(r'\s*ab\s*', " ", 'This is a ab text')
print(t)

This is a text
```

The above pattern `\s*ab\s*` matches and consumes `ab` along with any surrounding spaces, and then replaces with just a single space.

For the edge case where `ab` might be the very first or last word in a string, I recommend using `strip()`, e.g.

```
t = re.sub(r'\s*ab\s*', " ", 'ab tests can be so boring ab').strip()
print(t)

tests can be so boring
```